# Dragging from one layout to another throws "android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView"

Tags: android, android-layout

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    private float dX;
    private float dY;
    ImageView tmpView;
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //v.setBackground(targetShape); //change the shape of the view
                break;

            //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //v.setBackground(normalShape); //change the shape of the view back to normal
                break;

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                dX = view.getX() - event.getX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getY();

                tmpView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                tmpView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView) view).getDrawable());

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
                params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX();
                params.topMargin = (int) event.getY();
                mFrameLayout.addView(tmpView, params);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ivLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tmpView.getLayoutParams();
                ivLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (event.getX());
                ivLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) (event.getY() - 250);
                tmpView.setLayoutParams(ivLayoutParams);


                break;

            //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //v.setBackground(normalShape); //go back to normal shape

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Here `mFrameLayout` is the frameLayout in my xml.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true">

</FrameLayout>
```

The Drag works properly but when dropping into the frameLayout it throws `.FrameLayout cannot be cast to ImageView` at line this: 
`tmpView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView) view).getDrawable());`
The Draglistener is registered to the frame layout as `mFrameLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());`

I have read that for dropping an image FrameLayout is best, but I am not able to drop the image to the FrameLayout from my other Layout.

**UPDATE**:

Now my error does not appear, but the image does not appear at the drop location too:

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    private float dX;
    private float dY;
    ImageView tmpView;
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //v.setBackground(targetShape); //change the shape of the view
                break;

            //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //v.setBackground(normalShape); //change the shape of the view back to normal
                break;

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();

                if(mLinearLayout.getParent() != null){
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) draggedView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(draggedView);
                    mLinearLayout.removeView(draggedView);
                }
                mLinearLayout.addView(draggedView);

                internalImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                view.invalidate();

                break;

            //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //v.setBackground(normalShape); //go back to normal shape

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

My xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPlaceHolder"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_width="375dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cast_album_art_placeholder"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the StartDrag method being

```
mImageViewHolder.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new DragShadowBuilder(mImageViewHolder);

            // Starts the drag
            view.startDrag(null, // the data to be dragged
                    myShadow, // the drag shadow builder
                    view, //  need to use local data
                    0 // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
            );
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I can now drag and drop from one layout to another but the only one image can be dragged and dropped. I cannot repeat for other images.

Comment: Updated a fix, but working only for first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

The Drag Listener is now written like this.

```
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

private ImageView internalImageView;

class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;

            //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();

                if(mLinearLayout.getParent() != null){
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) draggedView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(draggedView);
                    mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                    //mLinearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                }
                mLinearLayout.addView(draggedView);
                mLinearLayout.invalidate();

                internalImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                view.invalidate();


                break;

            //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //## Heading ##view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.carouselView).invalidate();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```